# Align two text inside <P> Tag Using Css Instead of &nbsp;

Tags: html, css

I am using `nbsp;` to aligh the text. Is there any easy way to do it using CSS?

```
    <p>Website:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://www.helloworld.com</p>
    <p>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;support@helloworld.com</p>
    <p>Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00-554422000</p>
    <p>Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Secret Service HQ</p>
    <p>Postal Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;89509</p>
    <p>City:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3829 Martha Ellen Drive</p>
    <p>Region:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reno, NV</p>
```

Comment: You are supposed to (re)search first and only ask when documentation is unclear. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not looking to use a table:

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#details>*{
  display:block;
}
label{
  float:left; width:100px;
}
#map{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='details'>
      <label for='web'>Website:</label>
      <a id='web' href='https://www.helloworld.com'>https://www.helloworld.com</a>
      <label for='mail'>Email:</label>
      <a id='mail' href='mailto:support@helloworld.com'>support@helloworld.com</a>
      <label for='phone'>Phone:</label>
      <a id='phone' href='tel:00554422000'>00-554422000</a>
      <a id='map' href='https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Reno,+NV/@39.557847,-119.9909255,11z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x809940ae9292a09d:0x40c5c5ce7438f787!2m2!1d-119.8138027!2d39.5296329'>Not the Secret Service HQ</a>
      <label for='adr'>Address:</label><div id='adr'>3829 Martha Ellen Drive</div>
      <label for='cs'>City &amp; State</label><div id='cs'>Reno, NV</div>  
      <label for='zip'>Postal Code:</label><div id='zip'>89509</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Here is one:
HTML

```
<p>
Address<span class="spacer"></span>1234
</p>
```

CSS

```
.spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Simply make the width of the span be the amount of space you want.

Comment: Let me try. Thank you

Comment: Well, it doesn't work since all left side text arent same so space isn't equal. I actually want to align the right side texts.

Comment: Consider the tabular answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table!

You can increase the `padding-right` value for the first-child `td` to create more distance between the columns if you need.

```css
td:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Website:</td>
    <td>https://www.helloworld.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>support@helloworld.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone:</td>
    <td>00-554422000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td>Secret Service HQ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postal Code:</td>
    <td>89509</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td>3829 Martha Ellen Drive</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Region:</td>
    <td>Reno, NV</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: to the downvoters: This IS tabular data, there's no reason NOT to use a table

Comment: I agree, table seems like a totally valid way to format this data.

Comment: The answer strays from the question being asked and is therefore not helpful for the general case and for future visitors. Not to mention it lacks responsiveness, which is important, nowadays. Besides, considering the lack of (re)search of the question, answering it encourages future low-quality and unresearched questions. Please read [answer]. Overall, questions and answers like this are lowering the quality and usefulness of [so], IMHO. And no, a list is not tabular data. Tabular data is when you can draw a line at the end and sum up a column. The above is a list.

Comment: @Johannes, This is exactly what I wanted. But Is there any way to use CSS instead of table?

Comment: It is possible to apply table-like css to non-table HTML elements (using `display: table` and similar properties), but you still need to create a similar HTML block-like structure for that, so that wouldn't really make sense or have any advantage over a regular table.